# Does adding a volume to docker-compose recreate the container and delete the data within the container whose definition changed?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have a running DB container and the volume I defined for docker-compose is pointing to the wrong place in the container.

I need that data.

Can I just change the container path destination in the docker-compose definition or will that recreate the container and delete the data?

I know I can back up, stop the container, then make the volume change but I'm hoping I can get away with no downtime at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `docker-compose.yml` file, and re-run `docker-compose up`, Compose will delete and recreate containers as necessary to take those changes into account.  It won't touch anything it doesn't need to, and it will especially try hard to not delete volumes.

Just changing a volume's mount path should be safe:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  name:
    ...
    volumes:
      # - my-data:/wrong/path  # The container will get destroyed,
      - my-data:/right/path    # but the existing volume will get remounted
volumes:
  my-data:                     # without being changed
```

(If you have an anonymous volume – the volume definition was just `/wrong/path` – you probably need to do some manual work to preserve its contents, and specifying a volume without a name for `/right/path` will create a new different anonymous volume.)